# how to get any random time between now and last three hours using Java

Tags: java, random, time

Can anyone please tell me how to get any random time between now and last three hours using **Java 1.7**

Here is the lines I wrote to generate a random number:

```
Random random = new Random();

for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
    int randomInteger = random.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Random Integer in Java: " + randomInteger);
}
```

But how to get any random time between now and last three hours ?

Comment: Generate a number between zero and `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(3)`; subtract this from `System.currentTimeMillis()` (assuming you mean "3 standard hours").

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the reply. Can you provide me a little more details on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following?

```
    Date now = new Date();
    long timeRangeMs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3; // 3 hours in ms
    long random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(timeRangeMs);
    Date randDate = new Date(now.getTime() - random);
```

Comment: `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(3)`

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Can we use `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(3)` instead of `long timeRangeMs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3;`

Comment: @AlexMan - Yes - it is recommended to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class RandomTime 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println(d);

        Random r = new Random();
        int startTime = d.getMinutes();
        int endTime = low + 180;    // 3 hours
        int result = r.nextInt(endTime - startTime) + startTime;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, result);
        d.setMinutes(result);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```