# Get a random time between two time

Tags: android, calendar

Time 1 : `10:30 06/05/2018`

Time 2 : `19:45 06/05 2018`

I want to pick a random time between these two time. The result may be (`13:15 06/05/2018`).

I look into Calendar but seem it does not support a method like `range(time1, time2)`

What is the solution for this case ? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016336/how-to-generate-a-random-timestamp-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802925/how-to-get-any-random-time-between-now-and-last-three-hours-using-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802925/how-to-get-any-random-time-between-now-and-last-three-hours-using-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like this.

```
public static Calendar getRandomTime(Calendar begin, Calendar end){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        long min = begin.getTimeInMillis();
        long max = end.getTimeInMillis();
        long randomNum = min + rnd.nextLong()%(max - min + 1);
        Calendar res = Calendar.getInstance();
        res.setTimeInMillis(randomNum);
        return res;
    }
```

if you have API 21+, use ThreadLocalRandom

```
public static Calendar getRandomTime(Calendar begin, Calendar end){
    long randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(begin.getTimeInMillis(), end.getTimeInMillis() + 1);
    Calendar res = Calendar.getInstance();
    res.setTimeInMillis(randomNum);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should convert your times objects to `long` first as follows (I suppose that you have two `Calendar` objects already)

```
long time1InLong = time1.getTimeInMillis();
long time2InLong = time2.getTimeInMillis();
```

Then you can use following code to generate random number

```
Random r = new Random();
long randomTime = r.nextLong(time2InLong - time1InLong) + time1InLong;
```

Then you can convert this `randomTime` back to `Calendar` as follows

```
// Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy");

// Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(randomTime);
```

Comment: random nextInt can not apply for a long value.

Comment: use nextLong instead